# why setItem aren't letting 'edit button' work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am trying to put a button of **edit** for each item with the help of simple hook. i have used **map** to see the elements of an item.... but somehow it's not working...while pressing the button nothing is showing.....
Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-worker-s0igh
app.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import TodoList from "./TodoFiles/TodoList";

const defaultItems = [
  { id: 1, title: "Write React Todo Project", completed: true },
  { id: 2, title: "Upload it to github", completed: false }
];

const App = () => {
  const [items,setItems]=useState(defaultItems)

    const editItem=({id,title})=>{
      setItems(items.map(p=>p.id===id?{...p,title}:p))

    }
  return (
     <div style={{ width: 400 }}>
      <hr />
      <TodoList
        items={items}
        editItem={editItem}/>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

TodoList.js:

```
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = ({ title, completed, editItem }) => {

  return (

    <div style={{ width: 400, height: 25 }}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} />
      {title}

      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => editItem(title)}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const TodoList = ({ items = [], index,editItem }) => {


  return items.map((p, index) => (
    <TodoItem
      {...p}
      key={p.id}
      index={index}
      editItem={editItem}
    />
  ));
};

export default TodoList;
```

i don't want to use useEffect or useReducer fro custom hook ... because i want to practice with basics. sorry for my frequent questions, i'm trying so hard to learn this reactjs and i dun want to give up... thanx in advance and if it is possible, will you put some explanations in a plain text, why it's not working.

Comment: You're only passing the title to editItem in your TodoItem what about the id?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass `id` to `editItem` function on button onClick in `TodoItem` component.

Also you shouldn't use old state in setState function like that (in `editItem` function). You should use an updater function argument. Thanks to that you always modify current state.

```
const editItem = ({id,title}) => {
   setItems(oldItems => (olditems.map(p=>p.id===id?{...p,title}:p)))
}
```

```html
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = ({id, title, completed, editItem }) => {

  return (

    <div style={{ width: 400, height: 25 }}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} />
      {title}

      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => editItem({id,title})}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const TodoList = ({ items = [], index,editItem }) => {


  return items.map((p, index) => (
    <TodoItem
      {...p}
      key={p.id}
      index={index}
      editItem={editItem}
    />
  ));
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: changed it....but still edit button isn't working....
const TodoItem = ({id, title, completed, editItem }) => {

  return (

    <div style={{ width: 400, height: 25 }}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={completed} />
      {title}

      <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => editItem({id,title})}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
const TodoList = ({ items = [], editItem }) => {


  return items.map((p) => (
    <TodoItem
      {...p}
      key={p.id}
      editItem={editItem}
    />
  ));
};

Comment: Does this make any sense? I mean you have changed only the variable name. But everything is same. How do you think it might work?? It’s still the change...not working... ultimately changing the variable has no effect

Comment: I didn't change only variable name, i added updater function:


setItems(oldItems => (olditems.map(p=>p.id===id?{...p,title}:p)))

Comment: I did the edit according to ur advice.Here is the codesand link : https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-worker-s0igh
I just dun know what to do? Should I have declare another function or toggle?